# Group action and Right action

Tags: group-theory, definition, group-actions

Sorry if this may seem trivial - I just started studying Group Theory. This is the problem:

> Prove that $(g,h) \rightarrow hg$ does not define a group action with $g$ acting on $h$. Prove instead that this defines an action of $G^\text{op} $ on $G$.

Here is my attempt to prove the problem:

> To show the first part, note that $(g,h) \rightarrow hg$ does not satisfy the criteria $g,(h,x)=(gh),x$ for $x\in X$ where $X$ is the set acted upon. This is because, we get $xhg=xgh$ which is not necessarily true.
>
> The second part is true because an operation $*'$ in $G^\text{op}$ is defined as $h*'g=g*h$. Where $*$ is the operation in $G$. This will then allow the mapping to satisfy the criteria of a group action. We have, $(g,(h,x))=(g, xh)=xhg$ and $((g*'h),x)=((h*g),x)=xhg$ thus the function obeys the associativity criteria. The identity $(e,x)$ is direct.

My problem is that I do not fully comprehend the original problem.

a) I do not know what it means by $hg$, whether it is with respect to the operation $*$ in $G$ or $*'$ in $G^\text{op}$.

b) I am not sure if my understanding of $G^\text{op}$ is correct, and if I have used the operations correctly.

May someone please explain if I have any mistakes?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What are $g$ and $h$ (elements of)?

Comment: @Uncountable, unfortunately I am only given the information as quoted in the problem...I assumed they are both elements of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $hg$ is with respect to the "normal" operation in $G$.

It looks like your understanding of $G^{\text{op}}$ is correct (set $G$ but with group operation "reversed").

My attack on the actual question would be:

For the first part, the set acted upon is the set of the elements of the group $G$. Now  let $g,g',h\in G$. Then for $(g,h)\mapsto hg$ to be an action we need $(gg',h)=(g,(g',h))$, but $(gg',h)=hgg'$ and $(g,(g',h))=(g,hg')=hg'g$. These are not necessarily equal if $G$ isn't abelian.

For the second part, we get: 
$$(g*'g',h)=(g'g,h)=hg'g$$
and (still):
$$(g,(g',h))=(g,hg')=hg'g$$
So $(g*'g',h)=(g,(g',h))$, which is what we want for this to be an action of $G^{\text{op}}$ on $G$.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's worth specifying that in the first part $g, h \in G$, and in the second, $g, h \in G^{op}$. Anyway, in (a), the operation in $hg$ is $\ast$; in fact, you use just this in your solution to (b), which looks good to me.